# Hi I am new to google scripts, how do I parse a webhook?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, webhooks

I have some code being sent from my POS, I have added a google script to my spreadsheet, and it receives the webhook data. Though It separates the timestamp into one cell, then a couple of blank cells, then this whole string in the last cell.
Here is the [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjbtc.jpg) from google sheets. Where the string below is in the 6th cells.

```
{ text:
   'A Payment was made\n\nFor customer Cash Drawer Register for amount: 1.0 the message\nwas:',
  html:
   'A Payment was made \n\n For customer Cash Drawer Register for amount: 1.0 the message was: ',
  link: 'https://****.****.com/payments/****',
  attributes:
   { id: 12986288,
     created_at: '2019-04-10T11:35:05.832+10:00',
     updated_at: '2019-04-10T11:35:05.832+10:00',
     success: true,
     payment_amount: 1,
     invoice_ids: [ 14066768 ],
     ref_num: '',
     applied_at: '2019-04-10',
     payment_method: 'Cash',
     transaction_response: null,
     customer:
      { id: 7960296,
        firstname: 'Cash Drawer',
        lastname: 'Register',
        fullname: 'Cash Drawer Register',
        business_name: 'Cash Drawer Register',
        email: null,
        phone: null,
        mobile: null,
        created_at: '2017-02-02T09:12:09.186+11:00',
        updated_at: '2019-04-10T11:35:05.828+10:00',
        pdf_url: null,
        address: null,
        address_2: null,
        city: null,
        state: null,
        zip: null,
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        notes: null,
        get_sms: false,
        opt_out: false,
        disabled: false,
        no_email: false,
        location_name: null,
        location_id: null,
        properties: {},
        online_profile_url: null,
        tax_rate_id: null,
        notification_email: null,
        invoice_cc_emails: null,
        invoice_term_id: null,
        referred_by: null,
        ref_customer_id: null,
        business_and_full_name: 'Cash Drawer Register - Cash Drawer Register',
        business_then_name: 'Cash Drawer Register' } } }
```

I am just using this basic webhook script below, so I just need help to parse it so I can retrieve the details in the code above. I need: 
id:
firstname:
lastname:
amount:
In separate cells like this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzjdP.jpg)

```
 //this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);
  var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var testRunUrl = myData.test_run_url;
  var testRunName = myData.test_name;
  var testRunEnv = myData.environment_name;
  var testRunResult = myData.result;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(timestamp);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(testRunName);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(testRunEnv);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(testRunResult);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(testRunUrl);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

Comment: You need to show what `e.postData.contents` look like, the expected result screenshot and what have you tried to accomplish your goal with a clear problem statement. Read [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Why is 'Can someone help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I apologise I have never used Stack Overflow before, hopefully the edit is clearer now. I am not sure how to get what e.postData.contents looks like other then the string in the first code. Thank you

Comment: You should setValue proper params. Something like `myData.attributes.customer.id`

Comment: Awesome it worked, I am setting params like a pro. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?

```
function doPost(e) {
      var content = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

      return ContentService
              .createTextOutput()
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
              .setContent(JSON.stringify(content));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jess, Thank you I just tried it but it still outputs the same in the google sheet. This is what it outputs.
![Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dqwKcasINrWPX3IEuZm4wOzP9b_VIBiS/view?usp=sharing)